# "generator.exe" exited with code "-1073741819"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, jar, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'am developing a android application in Visual Studio and the Xamarin c# monodroid development tools.
I have some external JAR files that i embed into my projects. Most of the project work fine but when i try to embed the JAR from Yocto ([yocto android lib](http://www.yoctopuce.com/FR/downloads/YoctoLib.android.11167.zip)) and place the YoctoAPI.jar into a new android project and link it as "EmbeddedJar" the compiler fails with the exception "generator.exe" exited with code -1073741819.
This is a NULL pointer exception in the generator and searching the net i found some people who have the same problem and tells me that obfuscated code is not supported (that i understand). But how can i find the obfuscated code in the JAR file? Or is there a other problem that i'am not seeing.

If i need to post more project settings or envirioment/system parameters, please let me know

Comment: I am also facing same kind of issue. I have added one aar file which has some java based jar and some kotlin based.  Getting “generator.exe” exited with code “-1073741819”

Answer (score 0):

Such issues with Visual Studio can be fixed by repairing it.

You need to repair Visual Studio. Go to **Control Panel** -> **Programs**. Then select your version of Visual Studio you are using and press "**Change**"(or right click it and press "**Change**"). When the setup appears, click "**Repair**".

Answer (score 0):

I got same error while create binding project, in my case the problem is in resource file, you need to add the jar file and resource file like,

[image]

bin - contains all jar files,

res - contains all resource files,

and add the compressed '**bin**' folder in your project and build works fine.