# Getting an Error- "generator.exe" exited with code -532462766" - RazorPay Integration

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Getting an Error- "generator.exe" exited with code -532462766" while converting the Razorpay .aar file into DDL by using the Xamarin android binding project.

Build Action: **LibraryprojectZip** [click to view current configuration details of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9grI.png)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558176/generator-exe-exited-with-code-1073741819 any Kotlin stuff in that file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56737720/issue-in-binding-aar-file-having-kotlin-code-in-xamarin

Comment: Which version of razorpay are you using?

Comment: 3.8.10 (newest version) is targeting android api level 29, when you use this version you cant go lower then that

Comment: Thanks, I used level 29, and it's working...fine