# JAR to DLL with IKVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, dll, jar

I'm trying to convert a JAR file to DLL to use in my Xamarin app.

I do the code `ikvmc.exe myjar.jar` and then it generates the DLL file. I go to the references and add it, but when I compile I get the error: `Cannot resolve reference IKVM.Runtime, referenced by MyDllGenerated. Add NuGet package or an assembly reference`.

If I add IKVMRuntime.dll to my project it gaves me an error that the jars are identicals, but with different contents.

How can I generate this DLL to use in my project? Is there another way (except creating by Android Binding Library, I already tried and it gaves me an error of generator.exe)?

Comment: creating a Binding Library is the correct way

Comment: But what I do if I try to create it and gaves me an error about generator.exe?

Comment: here is document about binding java library in xamarin https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT ok no problem, it's ok to me to do it, but, when it will compile, Visual Studio returns an error "generator.exe", like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558176/generator-exe-exited-with-code-1073741819). I already repaired my VS, it compiled one time and then the errors returns to appear.

Comment: try install the lastest version of vs and follow this  tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar